# Timezone in PHP error log

Tags: php, linux, timezone, rsyslog

My PHP error log has the wrong timezone listed. I have the correct timezone on my system as can be seen by typing the **date** command at the Debian command prompt. I have restarted rsyslogd by typing **service rsyslog restart**. I have even rebooted the server just to make sure. Any ideas what is wrong here?

Comment: There's a separate `php.ini` setting for the timezone.

Comment: Doesn't php.ini take the system timezone if nothing is specified here?

Comment: Older versions did. Nowadays it demands to be hand-fed.

Comment: Also, doesn't the timezone in php.ini just apply to date functions?

Comment: Thank you Mario. I have done that and it fixed the problem. I had read a couple of other places that the dates listed in the error log file were determined by syslog and not by php. I guess I was reading incorrect (or old) information. Thanks!

Comment: Any ideas were php.ini gets its default timezone from when it is not set in php.ini?